# What is the closed form for the general recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form

$T(N) = a\cdot T(N-b) + c \cdot N + d $

$T(0) = 0$

I honestly don't understand this concept at all. Any help would be great.

Comment: This problem is not well-posed; $T(N)$ relies only on $T(N-b)$ and you've only specified $T(0)$. For instance, suppose $b = 2$; then $T(2)$ is determined, but $T(1)$ is not. Is there a typo?

Comment: there may be several cases, depending on the values of a, b, and c. N is assumed to be a variable of b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We usually write such relations as follows:

$$T_n - a T_{n-b} = c n + d$$

with initial condition:

$$T_0 = 0$$

where at least $n \ge 0$ and $b$ are integers.  In this case, your initial condition is only sufficient to specify a unique solution when $|b| = 1$.

A recurrence like this is what we call *inhomogeoneous* because the right hand side is nonzero.  In this case, the solution has two pieces: a homogeneous part and an inhomogeneous part.  The homogeneous part satisfies

$$T_n^{(H)} - a T_{n-b}^{(H)} = 0$$

with $T_n^{(H)}$ satisfying the specified initial conditions.  In this case, assume $b=1$.  We find in this case that

$$T_n^{(H)} = R a^n$$

for some constant $R$.  I'll come back to this.

To find this inhomogeneous piece $T_n^{(I)}$, one way to proceed is to look at the right-hand side and guess.  In this case, we might guess that $T_n^{(I)} = p n+q$, and solve for $p$ and $q$.  Doing this, we see that

$$T_n^{(I)} - a T_{n-1}^{(I)} = (p n+q) - a (p (n-1)+q) = p (1-a) + q (1-a + a p) = c n + d$$

We may now solve for the unknowns $p$ and $q$ in terms of the knowns $a$, $c$, and $d$:

$$p (1-a) = c$$
$$q (1-a + a p) = d$$

from which we get that

$$T_n^{(I)} = \frac{c}{1-a} n + \frac{(1-a) d}{(1-a)^2 + a c} $$

and our general solution is

$$T_n = R a^n + \frac{c}{1-a} n + \frac{(1-a) d}{(1-a)^2 + a c} $$

Now go back to our initial condition: $T_0 = 0$.  This means that

$$R + \frac{(1-a) d}{(1-a)^2 + a c} = 0$$

which determines $R$, and $T_n$, uniquely.  I hope this helps some.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write all this out. This does help answer my question. I appreciate it.

Comment: My pleasure, anytime.